# What does GEE do with mode ties?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

What does Google Earth Engine do with tied values when calculating the mode, in any context (for example, using ee.Reducer.mode, or ee.ImageCollection.mode)?

If there are an equal number of two values, for example, does it take the mean of the tied values?

Answer (score 1):

Based on some empirical tests, a mode with equal counts seems to return the lowest value:

```js
var numbers = ee.List([1, 10]);
print(numbers.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode())); 
// 1

var numbers = ee.List([1, 0]);
print(numbers.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode())); 
// 0

var numbers = ee.List([99, 30, 42]);
print(numbers.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode())); 
// 30
```

This also applies to image collections:

```js
var geom = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]);
var imgs = ee.ImageCollection([
  ee.Image(-100).int(),
  ee.Image(100).int(),
]);

print(imgs.mode().reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mode(), geom).get("constant"));
// -100
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately I don't have a solid answer, because in part this depends on a few things. What image or image collections are you using and what's the spatial resolution?  Also, what size of areas are you reducing over? These matter because they determine the count of pixels, and ee will treat smaller counts differently than larger counts, as said [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-mode). If you have smaller counts, then it should be straightforward to test this because you know ee will count the numbers directly. Larger areas would be more difficult to test since it's calculated from histograms.